# Row level calculation in tables using SQL

Tags: sql, logic, teradata

I have a table in the format:

```
Account| Sum Paid| Date 
1001   | 100.00  | 1/1/2019
1001   | -100.00 | 2/1/2019
1001   | 100.00  | 5/2/2019
1001   | -100.00 | 9/2/2019
```

The -ve amount shows the cancelled deal. In the example here, there are two cases of cancelled amounts, but in my dataset, there are lots of such records having different timestamps. I want my result set to look something like:

```
Account| Sum Paid| Date     | Days to cancel
1001   | -100.00 | 2/1/2019 | 1
1001   | -100.00 | 9/2/2019 | 4
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I am using Teradata and SQL. 
I tried creating two separate tables - one having positive amounts and one having negative amounts, but I'm unable to reach the desired output.

Any help will be appreciated.

(I'm using plain SQL for querying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume that each negative value is preceded by a positive value (with no intervening negative values) and that the dates are unique for a given account.  This is 100% consistent with your sample data.

In that case, you can simply use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, (date - prev_date) as diff
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by account order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where sum_paid < 0;
```

If the assumptions are not true, then I would recommend asking a *new* question and providing appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Good solution, I tested it and it does work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful reply. But there's just one minor case to consider. Not every transaction starts with a positive amount. That needs to be captured as well. Kindly help.

Comment: @Gosree . . . As I state in the question:  if the data does not meet the assumed conditions, then I would recommend that you ask another question.  Be very clear on how you want the exceptions to the above rules to be handled.